# TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON Babel-cli

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to run a local dev server and I'm getting a babel error when building the code.

When I run "`npm start`" I'm getting the  error:
Couldn't find preset "env" relative to directory

If I run "`npm install --save babel-preset-env`" the previous error disappears and I'm getting the error:
Couldn't find preset "stage-2" relative to directory

If I run "`npm install --save babel-preset-stage-2`" I get the error:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
 at Object.stringify (<anonymous>)
 at stringify (C:\Users\oysta\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\node_modules\core-js\library\fn\json\stringify.js:4:26)
 at compile (C:\Users\oysta\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:105:42)
 at loader (C:\Users\oysta\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:144:14)
 at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\Users\oysta\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)
 at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
 at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
 at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
 at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:744:10)
 at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\oysta\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\lib\_babel-node.js:154:22)
```

It seems like I get this error when trying to load some kind of cache object:

```
 var cacheKey = (0, _stringify2.default)(opts) + ":" + babel.version;
```

In the modules section of my webpack.config.js I have:

```
  rules: [
  {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    include: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
    ],
    query: {
      // https://github.com/babel/babel-loader#options
      cacheDirectory: isDebug,

      // https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/
      babelrc: false,
      presets: [
        // A Babel preset that can automatically determine the Babel plugins and polyfills
        // https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env
        ['env', {
          targets: {
            browsers: pkg.browserslist,
          },
          modules: false,
          useBuiltIns: false,
          debug: false,
        }],
        // Experimental ECMAScript proposals
        // https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#presets-stage-x-experimental-presets-
        'stage-2',
        // JSX, Flow
        // https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-preset-react
        'react',
        // Optimize React code for the production build
        // https://github.com/thejameskyle/babel-react-optimize
        ...isDebug ? [] : ['react-optimize'],
      ],
      plugins: [
        // Adds component stack to warning messages
        // https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-source
        ...isDebug ? ['transform-react-jsx-source'] : [],
        // Adds __self attribute to JSX which React will use for some warnings
        // https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-self
        ...isDebug ? ['transform-react-jsx-self'] : [],
      ],
    },
```

Comment: This may be hard to diagnose without a full reproducible repository.

Comment: I can see tomorrow if I can do that. Is there any other file I can share on the meantime?

Comment: The error seems to be from `babel-node`, not from Webpack, so that might be a place to start. How are you calling `babel-node`  and do you have `.babelrc` files?

Comment: The framework didn't come with a .babelrc file. For babel-node I just uninstalled it and then ran "npm install --save babel-cli" which is supposed to include babel-node. I noticed it is trying to load env and stage-2 found in the webpack.config.js so I'm guessing it's only defined there. I'm kinda new to front end development :(